# Recaptcha in Phonegap Application

Tags: javascript, cordova, recaptcha

I am working on Phonegap Application for that i need recaptcha to be implemented.I went through some blog such as :

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/recaptcha/AuN2f7JrZTA/yMpYz9jFGKsJ

but all they are discussing about manual changes in cordova js.They are actually modifying cordova js code `window.location.protocol`

So my question is how can implement Recaptcha in Phonegap html page to prevent bots/spam ??Javascript code be added if require

Comment: Why you want to implement that? what are your thoughts?

Comment: @prady00 my index page contain a registration form that needs recaptcha to prevent  bots/spam attack.

Comment: your index page is catched on client side or you serve it from server?

Comment: @prady00..currently i am testing it with client side page..but it might change to server side in future case..nways if you still have some helpful implementation for either case,you can share it

Comment: If you are serving it from server side, use google recapthcha library

Answer (score -2):

Here is the link:

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/intro

You can use it just as you use in web apps